# Как создавать объект по нажатию кнопки

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как заставить прописанный мной объект для игры, создаваться только после нажатие игроком на кнопку 'Играть'. Я не смог разобраться в instance, а opacity не хочет работать в Unity, тоже самое и с GetActive. Возможно я не получил от программы какого-нибудь разрешения. Не знаю. 
Вот персонаж:

```
public class player : MonoBehaviour {

    Rigidbody2D rb = null;
    Fish fish = null;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        fish = GetComponent<Fish>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 force = new Vector2();
        float speed = fish.Speed * 2f * Time.deltaTime;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) force.y = speed;
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) force.y = -speed;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            force.x = speed;
            fish.Direction = 1;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            force.x = -speed;
            fish.Direction = -1;
        }

        force = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(force, speed);
        rb.AddForce(force);
    }
```

Я хотел сделать это в отдельном скрипте.

Answer (score 0):

На обработчик нажатия кнопки накидуете скрипт:

```
public GameObject go;

void Start() {
    Instantiate(go);
    //или так Instantiate(go, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

go - и есть ваш объект, который нужно создавать

Comment: Спасибо, если не трудно подскажите как в этой связке использовать OnClick или что-то подобное?

Comment: [почитайте тут](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html)

Answer (score 0):

За создание дубликата объекта отвечает метод [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html). Этому методу требуется ссылка на создаваемый объект (либо на префаб, либо на объект на сцене).

Для обработки нажатия на кнопку вам нужна ссылка на обрабатываемую кнопку (например, в виде сериализуемого поля, куда вы её перетащите на сцене).
Нужный вам код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject _prefab; //Ссылка на ваш префаб

    [SerializeField]
    Button _button;

    void Start()
    {
        _button.onClick.AddListener(Spawn); //здесь мы добавляем к событию onClick нашей кнопки слушателя Spawn
    }

    void Spawn()
    {
        // _button.onClick.RemoveListener(Spawn); если вам нужно лишь единоразовое создание, то раскомментируйте эту строку. Сразу после вызова произойдёт отписка от события клика кнопки.
        Instantiate(_prefab);
    }
}
```